# I want to make 1st column static with Tiny Table table sorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want 1st Column should always static and 1,2,3,4,5 Even if i sort with any other column With TinyTable. [image: Table Example]. is that possible...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done that by re-applying S#. every time.

```
   for (var i=0; i < t.l; i++) {
        this.t.r[i].cells[SERIAL_COLUMN].innerHTML = i+1;
    }
```